# How are Streetpass Puzzle Swap panels distributed in Europe / Australia?

Tags: streetpass, puzzle-swap, streetpass-mii-plaza

In the United States, Puzzle Swap panels appear to be distributed by State. That is, each state gets a particular puzzle, and to find other puzzles, you need to Streetpass with people in other states. It tied to your initial region selection, so unless you reformat the 3DS's system memory, you will always get the same initial panel.

Does anyone know how the puzzles are distributed in Europe? Is it broken down by country, or is (hopefully) more granular than that? My wife and I both live in Berlin, and we've now both completed the Mario, Luigi, and Bowser panel.

Comment: I don't know, but here in France, everybody has some piece of the Metroid puzzle (it was also the puzzle I got the first piece).

Comment: Hi my family and I live in Italy and we have completed the Pikmin and Mario bros. puzzles.
I will be going to the US this summer and hope to be able to find more panels. It seems to be everyone's question. How do you get new puzzle panels, mine too!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Nintendo's revamp of the Streetpass Puzzle system this question is irrelevant as-written, and the new way they're distributed is more transparent.

Different countries, and different regions in larger countries, still get different puzzles. These regions are identified in Streetpass Mii Plaza's map feature. On top of that there are special pieces you can't buy in particular regions at all and must Streetpass someone from another region to get; these are indicated by purple squares.

With the new system, new puzzles can also be distributed by Spotpass.

Answer (score 1):

In canada ontario, i finished the kirby puzzle... Only way to get another panel in same area is to have another 3ds and re-format it to different countries/ states inorder to get a new piece for a new panel

Answer (score 0):

Everyone in Western Australia (at least) starts off with pieces of the Super Mario Galaxy 2 puzzle. I wondered where people were getting their new panels from!